# Completion Suggester with additional conditions in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5, search-suggestion

I have a index that returns jobs in different languages.

I need to search similar jobs as per a single text that to a single language. So let's say, I have set 1 as LanguageId for English. And I want to search jobs matching with account. So if I write below query, it fetch jobs with all different languages. So basically the **"must"** query is not having any impact.

```css
GET jobs/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "languageid": "1"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "suggest": {
    "suggestions": {
      "text": "acce",
      "completion": {
        "field": "jobs.suggest",
        "size": 30
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My mapping looks as below

```js
   "mappings": {
"jobs": {
        "properties": {
          "@timestamp": {
            "type": "date"
          },
          "@version": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "industytype": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "jobs": {
            "properties": {
              "suggest": {
                "type": "completion",
                "analyzer": "simple",
                "preserve_separators": true,
                "preserve_position_increments": true,
                "max_input_length": 50
              }
            }
          },
          "language": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "type": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "updateddate": {
            "type": "date"
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you share your mapping details?

Comment: Adding the mapping on the question itself

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to filter out suggestions at query time, because `completion` suggester uses [FST](https://www.elastic.co/blog/you-complete-me) - special in-memory data structure that built at index time:

> Suggesters in Lucene are built in-memory by loading the completion values from the index, then building the FST. This can be a slow, resource intensive process. And, as soon as the index changes, the FST needs to be rebuilt. "Real time search" is a mantra of Elasticsearch. It is not acceptable to return out of date suggestions, nor to require a full rebuild whenever the index changes. **Instead of building the FST at search time, we now build an FST per-segment at index time.**

So all you can do is to add [context](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/suggester-context.html) for your suggester. Context also filled at index time along with `completion` field and therefore can be used at query time in `suggest` query. Also, this [article](https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-1-2-adding-context-suggestions) may be useful for you.

Comment: that is nice, but context using OR and not AND :(

Comment: Hi, do you know how we can sort results of completion suggestor??